# find cell reference of a cell from another cell in excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have a worksheet that returns a value from a different sheet in the sameworkbook (=data!C68) which returns a value.

Ina another cell I want to reference the reference in the original cell but increment the row by 1 - (=data!C69). The cells are not next to each other.

Is this possible either with a function or a fromula?

Thanks

Jonathan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Option Explicit
Function GetCellReferenceUsedInFormula(ByVal src As Range) As Range
If src.HasFormula Then
    Set GetCellReferenceUsedInFormula = Evaluate(Mid(src.Formula, 2))
End If
End Function
```

And use the above function in formula with `OFFSET`

```
=OFFSET(GetCellReferenceUsedInFormula(A1),1,0)
```

This is assuming that cell A1 contains the formula `=data!C68`.
Please note that the VBA code assumes that the formula is simple (i.e. `=somecellreference`).

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to achieve this. Here is one way. I have extended the function by incorporating the rows and columns that you want to Offset. Paste this code in a module

**Syntax**

=GetOffset(Range,Row,Col)

**Remarks**

*Range* (Required) is the cell which has the formula

*Row* (Optional) Row(s) you want to offset

*Col* (Optional) Column(s) you want to offset

**Sample Usage**

=GetOffset(A1) : This will pickup the value from the same cell which A1 is referring to. If A1 is referring to `=data!C69` then **GetOffset** will get value from data!C69

=GetOffset(A1,1) : This will pickup the value from the next cell (1 row down) which A1 is referring to. If A1 is referring to `=data!C69` then **GetOffset** will get value from data!C70

=GetOffset(A1,1,1) : This will pickup the value from the next cell (1 row down across 1 Col) which A1 is referring to. If A1 is referring to `=data!C69` then **GetOffset** will get value from data!D70

=GetOffset(A1,0,1) : This will pickup the value from the next cell (Same row across 1 Col) which A1 is referring to. If A1 is referring to `=data!C69` then **GetOffset** will get value from data!D69

**CODE**

```
Public Function GetOffset(Rng As Range, Rw As Long, Col As Long) As Variant
    Dim MyArray() As String, strTemp As String
    Dim TempRow As Long, TempCol As Long

    On Error GoTo Whoa

    Application.Volatile

    MyArray = Split(Rng.Formula, "!")

    TempRow = Range(MyArray(UBound(MyArray))).Row
    TempCol = Range(MyArray(UBound(MyArray))).Column

    TempRow = TempRow + Rw
    TempCol = TempCol + Col

    strTemp = MyArray(0) & "!" & Cells(TempRow, TempCol).Address

    GetOffset = Application.Evaluate(Trim(strTemp))
    Exit Function
Whoa:
End Function
```

Comment: wow, wow, wow. That is truly awesome, it works like a dream, I can't thank you enough, it has literally saved me hours. I really appreciate your help. Thanks Jonathan

Comment: Using `Application.Volatile` is not a good practice. i.e. the VBA code will execute whenever the calculate event occurs on the sheet, whether or not any dependent cells have changed.

Comment: It's not a good practice? I am sorry, but says who? :) I want it to recalculate and hence I included that :) Do you mean to say since NOW(), RAND() change on Calculate Event so it's bad? You have to use Application.Volatile judiciously as lengthy functions can make your worksheet slow other wise there is no problem.

Comment: I agree, I don't understand the implications of application.volatile but I just kkow that Siddharth's code works beuatifully and has saved me a whole bunch of time, for me, that's good practice!!! Thanks Jonathan

Comment: @SiddharthRout: Try a small function such as `Function test2() As String
    Application.Volatile
    test2 = "Hello world" msgbox "why is it hitting here?"
End Function` and use this in an excel cell (B1). Followed by that put a value 1 in cell A1, 2 in cell A2 and put a formula `=SUM(A1:A2)` in cell A3, you will see that the `test2` function gets called which I don't think should happen. Now, change the value in cell A1 to 2 (which will trigger the cell A3 to be recalculated). I ask the question, why should this function recalculate itself when none of its dependent parameters have changed?

Comment: Seems like you missed the point in my last comment... "You have to use Application.Volatile judiciously" I would never use "Application.Volatile" in a function which returns a Message Box ;)